# bootstrap-select scroll goes out of bounds

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and have a drop down select on my page. The issue is when I click on it, dropdown list appears, but it does not fit into area, calculated for it, and scroller flows down below the area. It looks like following:

[image: pic]

HTML for this:

```
<form role="form" id="condition_form_check" method="post" class="form-horizontal condition_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Check</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
                            <select id="has_id" name="has_id" size="1" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" title="select check..." tabindex="-98">
                                <option value="1">check_1</option>
                                <option value="2">check_2</option>
                                <option value="3">check_3</option>//etc...   
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The problem is that sometimes it looks ok, some times with this bug. After some research I found out that some inline CSS styles are applied to `select` tag:

```
max-height:255px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

which go (presumably) from the following source lines (around 1057):

```
$menuInner.css({
      'max-height': menuHeight - menuPadding.vert + 'px',
      'overflow-y': 'auto',
      'min-height': ''
    });
```

But i dont know how to fix this issue. Any ideas would be welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set form-control's height value "auto" on your css.Likely

```
.form-control{
  height:auto;
 }
```

And also set max-height is 100%

```
form-control{
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
 }
select{
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: with `.form-control` css styles scroller looks incorrectly, lower arrow disappears, the list does not fit into area calculated for it.